# Is foreign key reference from two different primary key from two different tables valid?

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb

I have a foreign key that has to refer primary keys of two different tables.

Table 1: animal

```
       animal_ id (primary key)
```

Table 2: bird

```
       bird_ id (primary key)
```

Table 3: Pet_info

```
      pet_id,
      type ENUM ('bird', 'animal')
      foreign key (pet_ id) references animal(animal_id), bird(bird_id)
```

So, I need to check for pet_id either from animal or bird table depending on the need. Is this valid? Or should I go for some restructuring . . .

**NOTE:** [I referred this . .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056918/reference-key-from-either-of-two-different-tables) but I'm not sure whether I have to change my existing design

Comment: It appears that you have the foreign keys in the wrong place. I would have expected the foreign key to be animal_id and bird_id in their respective tables, which would reference the parent Pet table (supertype/subtype pattern).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this page: http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=subclass.php Do a pet_id in the animal and bird table.

Answer (score -2):

This is bad design. Have one table for all pets with all their attributes, one of which will be the type.